# Jenkins ssh agent, private key without password

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to get my Jenkins publish files over ssh. I use pipeline scripts, that is because I have to use the ssh agent. But I am not able to configure it correctly, it is always throwing an exception. This is what I did so far for debugging:

I configured ssh credentials on the "Publish over SSH" part in global settings and as credentials (SSH Username with private key).
I use a file on the master without passphrase.

I created a freestyle job and configured the "Publish SSH"-Plugin to make an "ls" on the remote machine. This works.
I checked the box to use "ssh agent", but this leads to an exception:

```
[ssh-agent] Looking for ssh-agent implementation...
[ssh-agent]   Java/JNR ssh-agent
[ssh-agent] Skipped registering BouncyCastle, not running on a remote agent
[ssh-agent] Started.
[ssh-agent] Unable to read key: Unable to create OpenSSL PBDKF: Could not generate secret key
org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMException: Unable to create OpenSSL PBDKF: Could not generate secret key
at org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.PEMUtilities.getKey(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.PEMUtilities.getKey(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.PEMUtilities.crypt(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcePEMDecryptorProviderBuilder$1$1.decrypt(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMEncryptedKeyPair.decryptKeyPair(Unknown Source)
at jenkins.bouncycastle.api.PEMEncodable.decode(PEMEncodable.java:162)
at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshagent.jna.JNRRemoteAgent.addIdentity(JNRRemoteAgent.java:79)
at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshagent.SSHAgentBuildWrapper$SSHAgentEnvironment.add(SSHAgentBuildWrapper.java:395)
at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshagent.SSHAgentBuildWrapper.preCheckout(SSHAgentBuildWrapper.java:229)
at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.preCheckout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:76)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:528)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Could not generate secret key
at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.generateSecret(SecretKeyFactory.java:347)
... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: password empty
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.OpenSSLPBKDF$PBKDF.engineGenerateSecret(Unknown Source)
at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.generateSecret(SecretKeyFactory.java:336)
... 15 more
```

I tried to type some dummy passphrase, this leads to a different exception (something with "check your credentials").
I tried to set the path for the key file to something different, this leads to a third exception (Like FileNotFound)

There is no difference between running on master or slave.

The error message "password empty" looks as if the empty passphrase makes problems - but the "publish over ssh" plugin has no problems with it, so I think it should be ok like this.

I have no idea what else I could check. I am near to create a freestyle job with "publish over ssh" which is triggered by my pipeline job... but seriously this is not the way it should be done?...